# EOS transaction using RPC

Tags: eos

I am trying to build a EOS transaction manually by querying the EOS(Jungle testnet endpoint) using CURL. I can get some information about the accounts using CURL. Can anyone please tell me the steps to do a simple transaction from Account A to account B using RPC and endpoints(without local node installation).

Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a transaction from account A to account B requires signature from account A, so for that you'll need to setup wallet (keosd) and to broadcast transaction you can setup the cli tool (cleos).
And then you can use the following command:

```
cleos -u https://api.jungle3.alohaeos.com push action eosio.token transfer '["from","to","1.0000 EOS", "memo"]' -p {fromaccount}@active
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EOSJS to send the transactions. Follow official documentation here: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/basic-usage/browser and here: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/how-to-guides/how-to-submit-a-transaction